# Understanding the button click in camera2 API in Camera2Basic in Android

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I'm trying to understand how the camera2 api works in the Google Camera2Basic sample code. Specifically, how does the 'Picture' button register the shot?

In onCreateViewCreated:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view.findViewById(R.id.picture).setOnClickListener(this);
    view.findViewById(R.id.info).setOnClickListener(this);
    mTextureView = (AutoFitTextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.texture);
}
```

So `setOnClickListener()` registers the click? But what does it go to?  I see that **this** is passed in but I don't understand what's going on.

What I've normally done is do something like set up a button in `onCreateView()` and wire its `setOnClickListener()` to some action like so:

```
photoButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.picture);
photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.onSetClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //some action
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This same thing is happening in the example code. However, it looks a little different because the `Camera2BasicFragment` activity is implementing `OnClickListener`. Therefore, when the onClickListener is set, `this` is given to say that this activity will override the `onClick` method. So when the button is clicked the `onClick` method in the class is automatically called.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.picture: {
            takePicture();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.info: {
            Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (null != activity) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                        .setMessage(R.string.intro_message)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                        .show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```